# "await" results of tasks in Swift

Tags: asynchronous, swift3, async-await, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I come from a C# background and would like to implement awaiting functionality in my Swift app. I've achieved my desired results but I had to use a semaphore which I'm not sure is good practice. I have a function with an alamo request that returns a JSON with a success value and as I understand it that request function is async with a completion handler. The handler fires once the request is complete. The problem is returning the success value from that operation. Here's a psuedo-code example of what I'm doing:

```
func AlamoTest() -> Bool{
var success = false
//Do some things...
//...
//Signal from async code
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
Alamofire.request("blah blah blah", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in {
    success = response["success"]
    if(success){
        //Do some more things
    }
    semaphore.signal() //Signal async code is done
}
//Wait until async code done to get result
semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
return success
}
```

Is there a "better" way of achieving my goal? I'm new to Swift and its async constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found is what I call "callback chaining". Example of my method looks like this:

```
func postJSON(json: NSDictionary, function: ServerFunction, completionHandler: ((_ jsonResponse: NSDictionary) -> Void)? = nil) {
    //Create json payload from dictionary object
    guard let payload = serializeJSON(json: json) else {
        print("Error creating json from json parameter")
        return
    }

    //Send request
    Alamofire.request(urlTemplate(function.rawValue), method: .post, parameters: payload, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON { response in
        //Check response from server
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let jsonResponse = data as! NSDictionary
                print("\(jsonResponse)")
                //Execute callback post request handler
                if completionHandler != nil {
                    completionHandler!(jsonResponse)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                    print("Shit didn't work!\(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

The last parameter is a closure that executes once the orginal async operation is complete. You pass in the result to the closure and do what you want with it. In my case I wanted to disable the view while the async operations were rolling. You can enable the view in your closure argument since the result from the alamo async operation is called on the main thread. completionHandler defaults to nil if you don't need the result and stops the chaining.

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework for Swift coroutines - https://github.com/belozierov/SwiftCoroutine

```
func AlamoTest() throws -> Bool {
    try Coroutine.await() { callback in
        Alamofire.request("blah blah blah", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .default).responseJSON { response in
            let success = response["success"]
            callback(success)
        }
    }
}
```

and then call this method inside coroutine:

```
DispatchQueue.main.startCoroutine {
    let result = try AlamoTest()

}
```